# Subtract previous rows from first row by ID in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a variable that subtracts the previous row's date from the first row's date by an ID but starts over when another variable equals 1. Here is my dataset below:

```
data <- data.frame("ID" = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2), "Date" = c("2018-08-07","2018-08-08","2018-08-09","2018-08-09","2018-08-10","2018-08-11","2018-08-11","2018-08-12","2018-08-04","2018-08-07","2018-08-07","2018-08-08","2018-08-09","2018-08-10"),"DRSG" = c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0))

ID     Date          DRSG      
1      2018-08-07    1
1      2018-08-08    0
1      2018-08-09    0
1      2018-08-09    0
1      2018-08-10    1
1      2018-08-11    0
1      2018-08-11    0
1      2018-08-12    0
2      2018-08-04    1
2      2018-08-07    0
2      2018-08-07    0
2      2018-08-08    1
2      2018-08-09    0
2      2018-08-10    0
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
ID     Date          DRSG    days
1      2018-08-07    1       0
1      2018-08-08    0       1
1      2018-08-09    0       2
1      2018-08-09    0       2
1      2018-08-10    1       0
1      2018-08-11    0       1
1      2018-08-11    0       1
1      2018-08-12    0       2
2      2018-08-04    1       0
2      2018-08-07    0       3
2      2018-08-07    0       3
2      2018-08-08    1       0
2      2018-08-09    0       1
2      2018-08-10    0       2
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a cumulative sum on the original `DRSG` column grouped by `ID`. We can then use *this* new column in conjunction with the original `ID` as our group. From there we leverage `dplyr::first` to do the subtraction.

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(increment_DRSG = cumsum(DRSG)) %>%
  group_by(ID, increment_DRSG) %>%
  mutate(days = Date - first(Date))
```